# Why is github pages showing a different date for my post (w/ Jekyll)?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, broken-links

I publish [my blog](http://strilanc.com/) using github pages. Recently I noticed a permalink to one of the posts broke.

It [used to be](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1ztgen/building_your_own_quantum_fourier_transform/) this:

> http://strilanc.com/quantum/2014/03/07/Building-your-own-Quantum-Fourier-Transform.html

but now it's this:

> http://strilanc.com/quantum/2014/03/06/Building-your-own-Quantum-Fourier-Transform.html

The date shown for the post is also one day earlier than what's specified in the [filename and metadata at the start of the contents](https://github.com/Strilanc/Strilanc.github.io/blob/caf8fd3e98734535f07b8c7c89a3b3d0a295f248/_posts/2014-03-07-Building-your-own-Quantum-Fourier-Transform.markdown):

> Filename: 2014-03-07-Building-your-own-Quantum-Fourier-Transform.markdown
>
> ```
> ---
> layout: post
> title: "Building your own Quantum Fourier Transform"
> date: 2014-03-07 0:30:01
> categories: quantum
> ---
> ```

Even more strangely, the local server I run with `jekyll serve` *does* show the right date, and use the right permalink.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive on this but is it possible that since there is no timezone information in that date that it is being converted when it is built?

Just as an FYI, if you didn't know already, that date is not necessary unless you need to maintain order of posts in a more granular way than the date in the filename.

No definitive answer here just some thoughts and comments.

Comment: You nailed it. There was a timezone conversion happening that pushed the time across midnight. I moved the time to noon-ish EST and the day went back to the correct value.

Comment: There's an issue submitted to the Jekyll repo about it already: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1069

Comment: (and the reason it *used* to work is I recently moved between time zones)